# Verification of these calculations involving a matrix with singularity

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $\;A=\begin{pmatrix}
>            \cos\theta&0&\sin\theta\\0&1&0\\-\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta
>            \end{pmatrix}\;$ and $\;B=\begin{pmatrix}
>            0&0&-1\\0&1/x_2&0\\1&0&0
>            \end{pmatrix}\;$ and take $\;x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb R^3\;$.
>
> If $\;x=A^Ty\;$ where $\;A^T\;$ denotes the transpose matrix of
>   $\;A\;$ and $\;y\in \mathbb R^3\;$ then is it true to claim:
>
> $\;Bx=BA^Ty=A^TBy\;(*)$?
>
> **NOTE:**$\;B\;$ depends on $\;x\;$ in the sense that $\;\forall x\in \mathbb R^3\;\;Bx=\begin{pmatrix}
>             -x_3\\1\\x_1\\
>            \end{pmatrix}\;$

**My thoughts:**

Since $\;B, A^T\;$ commute i.e $\;BA^T=A^TB\;$ and $\;A^TBy\;$ is valid $\;\forall y\in \mathbb R^3\;$ then the above should be correct. However the fact that $\;B\;$ has this singularity for $\;x_2=0\;$ make me doubt about it.

Is $\;(*)\;$ well defined?

Any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the way the problem is structured (a rotation and an antidiagonal matrix), you can treat $x$-$z$ and $y$ separately.

Comment: @J.M. is not a mathematician Excuse me, but could you be more specific?  I see you suggest me to do something different but I can't see what exactly

Comment: I wanted you to notice that your problem *decouples* since the rotation and flipping is only happening to the $x$ and $z$ coordinates.

Comment: @J.M. is not a mathematician So the singularity   in the $/;y/; $ coordinate is not a problem  after all? The rotation is indeed in the $/;xz/; $ plane but I'm afraid $/; (*)/; $ doesn't hold because matrix  $/;B/; $ has only sense if it'multiplied by $/;x/; $ not $/;A^Tx/; $

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it. If you really want to convince yourself, you can do all the needed matrix multiplications.

Comment: @J.M is not a mathematician If I do the needed matrix multiplications then both $/;BA^Ty/;,/;A^TBy/; $ are defined.... but my professor said that  $/;B/; $ has only sense if it's multiplied by $/;x/; $. This is why I'm confused over $/; (*)/; $. Thanks a lot for your time however